# how to avoid printing 'echo' output with system command in C

Tags: html, c, unix, system, su

```
system("echo 'abcpasswd' | su - NewUsr -c 'ls -ltr'");
```

Above code embedded in my 'C' code which generats a binary , which is later called from a html page.
Now the above code prompts for a 'Password' which is piped in the command. But i end up seeing the prompt 'Password:' in my html rendered page.

How do i get around this ?. I don't want the prompt 'Password:' seen on my webpage.

Comment: Assuming "*abcpasswd*" to ***be*** the password, so exactly how does the string "*Password:*" gets printed?

Comment: The 'Password:' prompt is something similar to how you see in the shell password prompt. I'm aware of features in 'sudo' like below                                      NewUsr  ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL , but i want the password to be explicitly given as i did by using a pipe.

Comment: I thought su deliberately didn't let you pipe in a password.

Comment: I suppose you could make your own version of su that doesn't print "Password:" before letting you enter the password.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, `su` doesn't takes password everywhere else than from an interactive terminal. Option `-` is just for full login not for standard input reading.

You may use `sudo` which you can control better (read your OS manual about it), beware using such in non interactive mode is considered as harmful...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions and comments.
I found a way around this by handling it in the html/php side. By replacing 'passthru' by 'exec' and selectively picking what needs to be output to the page.